# Variable is empty when exporting to file

Tags: variables, batch-file

I'm trying to set a variable every time + 1 with a batch file. So when the batch file opens it calls the file with the var and then redefines it plus 1. But when i open the file and then open count.bat i see this(in count.bat): `set backupcount=` instead of 
`set backupcount=1` which it should be (1 can also be 2, 3, 4, 5, enz).

This is the code i'm using:

```
@echo off
if exist "backup-tool\count.bat" call "backup-tool\count.bat"

if not exist "backup-tool\count.bat" echo set backupcount=0 > "backup-tool\count.bat"

call "backup-tool\count.bat"

if "%backupcount%"=="8" (
    echo set backupcount=1 > "backup-tool\count.bat"
) else (
    set /a "backupcount=backupcount+=1"
    echo set backupcount=%backupcount% > "backup-tool\count.bat"
)

pause >nul
```

Anyone that knows what i'm doing wrong and tell me how i should do it?

All help is very much appreciated!

Comment: although `set /a "backupcount=backupcount+=1"` works, the correct syntax is either `set /a "backupcount=backupcount+1"` or `set /a "backupcount+=1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one needs to use `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, because you work in a block of code where you manipulate that variable and you want to use it right there(not the variable that is out of the block). This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if exist "backup-tool\count.bat" call "backup-tool\count.bat"

if not exist "backup-tool\count.bat" echo set backupcount=0 > "backup-tool\count.bat"

call "backup-tool\count.bat"

if "!backupcount!"=="8" (
    echo set backupcount=1 > "backup-tool\count.bat"
) else (
    set /a "backupcount=backupcount+=1"
    echo set backupcount=!backupcount! > "backup-tool\count.bat"
)

pause >nul
```

Comment: Thank you, it works and now i can prove that i can make a Back-up code that deletes backups older then one week!!

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem is related to Delayed Expansion as other answer said; however, your code is also unnecessarily complex. This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off

if exist "backup-tool\count.bat" call "backup-tool\count.bat"
set /A "backupcount=backupcount%%8+1"
echo set "backupcount=%backupcount%" > "backup-tool\count.bat"
```

The `set /A` command takes as zero the value of any non-existent variable, so it is not necessary to initialize it with zero when the data file not exists.

If you want a repeating count from 1 to 8 and then reset the counter to 1, you may use the `%` Modulus operator in a simpler way that don't require an `if`. Type `set /?` for further details on `%%` operator, or see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

**EDIT**: *Additional explanations added*

The first time the program run the `backupcount` variable does not exist, so the `set /A "backupcount=backupcount%%8+1"` expression generate a `1` that is stored in the file. You may also add a `set backupcount=0` command *before* the `if` just to avoid problems with previous executions of the same Batch file (or add a `setlocal` command at beginning).

The next time this variable is initialized with `1`, so `set /A "backupcount=backupcount%%8+1"` expression produce a `2`. The same happen with next numbers up to `8`.

When the variable is initialized with `8` the expression `backupcount%%8`, that is the remainder when the variable is divided by 8, is zero; so the whole expression produce a `1` again.

Comment: Thank you for commenting but there is no way to use that code in my opinion, althought i will look to the reset function! Maybe you could explain it here?

Comment: Did you tested my code? I am pretty sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes iT worked but unfortunely i can't use iT in my opinion And i changed Some plans do.

Comment: But do i'm very thankfull for helping me! I did used a little but of your code.